# Oracle procedure compilation error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

DB Version : Oracle 11.2.0.2

Scenario : Trying to automate creation of range partitions using a procedure. Below is the code for that. It gets created without any error. But when I execute, it throws an error. I think the values am passing to the variables are not right. I tried with various sql's but nothing worked.Can someone please help me with this procedure.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MONTHLY_PARTITION as
  2
  3    v_partition_name varchar2(30);
  4    v_limit TIMESTAMP with local time zone;

  5    6  begin
  7
  8    select to_char(trunc(add_months(sysdate,1),'MM'),'MonYYYY')
  9    into v_partition_name
 10    from dual;
 11
 12    SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(current_timestamp, 2), 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  into v_limit from dual;
 13
 14  execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE TEST ADD PARTITION ' || v_partition_name || ' VALUES LESS    THAN (TIMESTAMP ' || v_limit || ')';
 15
 16  end;
 17  /

Procedure created.

SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL>
SQL> exec MONTHLY_PARTITION;
BEGIN MONTHLY_PARTITION; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14019: partition bound element must be one of: string, datetime or interval literal, number, or MAXVALUE
ORA-06512: at "MONTHLY_PARTITION", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 2):

what you have is actually OK. just a few datatype errors that is all!

you have to have your variable as `varchar2` and not `timestamp` when splicing it into the DDL.

ie:

```
SQL> create table TEST(dte timestamp)
  2  partition by range (dte)
  3  (PARTITION TODAY VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP'2012-02-01 00:00:00'));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MONTHLY_PARTITION as
  2
  3   v_partition_name varchar2(30);
  4   v_limit varchar2(30);
  5
  6    begin
  7
  8   select to_char(trunc(add_months(sysdate,1),'MM'),'MonYYYY')
  9   into v_partition_name
 10   from dual;
 11
 12   SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(current_timestamp, 2), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  into v_limit from dual;
 13
 14  execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE TEST ADD PARTITION ' || v_partition_name || ' VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP''' || v_limit || ''')';
 15
 16  end;
 17  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec monthly_partition

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select partition_name from user_tab_partitions where table_name = 'TEST';

PARTITION_NAME
------------------------------
TODAY
MAR2013
```

also note that your current expression `ADD_MONTHS(current_timestamp, 2)` isn't truncating to the month. did you want to do that too? i.e. `trunc(ADD_MONTHS(current_timestamp, 2), 'mm')`?

Comment: The truncate part in v_partition_name is for the Partition name, I want to have the partition name starting with the month like Mar2013, Apr2013 so on.. 
I tried to declare v_limit as varchar but it throwed an error below. Actually what I am trying to achieve through v_limt is, I want to add two months to current timestamp value. Not sure if that sql is exactly right and that's cauing the problem. Below is the table structure and the manual statement which I use to add partition. I want to schedule this procedure to run once at the end of every month and create a partition for next month.

Comment: SQL> exec MONTHLY_PARTITION;
    BEGIN MONTHLY_PARTITION; END;

    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
    ORA-06512: at "MONTHLY_PARTITION", line 10
    ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: create table test
    (testid NUMBER(2),
    CONFLICT_TIME TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE not null)
    partition by range ("CONFLICT_TIME")
    (PARTITION "Feb2013"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2013-03- 01    00:00:00.000000000+00:00'));

Comment: ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION Mar2013 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2013-04-01 00:00:00.000000000+00:00');

Answer (score 1):

assign this to a string variable:

```
    str := 'ALTER TABLE TEST ADD PARTITION ' || v_partition_name 
       || ' VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP ' || v_limit 
       || ')';
```

then

```
dbms_output.PUT_LINE( str );
execute immediate str;
```

see if the output str will run as you intend from sql plus

Comment: the message may indicate TIMESTAMP is not allowed - use DATETIME instead.

Comment: I tried the above code, still I get the same error. The column is partitioned on Timestamp with Local time zone field, so I have to pass that in my alter statement, can't use DATETIME

Comment: when you run the string in sql plus - if you get the same error - then all your code is correct - your statement contains an unsupported partition type.

Comment: When I run the alter table statement to add partition manually from sqlplus then it works without any error. But when I try to do this using a procedure by passing the timestamp value dynamically using the variable v_limit then it throws error. I don't understand if the value from v_limit is not what it is expecting or something else is wrong

Comment: make sure you are running this exact str variable as the statement in sqlplus. that should be the exact same thing that the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Partition values must be fixed and you have to manually handle them.You can't have an expression when you specify the value for the partition.

Comment: Does that mean we can't do this using a script at all or should I make changes to the procedure while passing those values